# Java, Drop-down list of integers

Tags: java, arrays, integer, dropdown

I am trying to have a drop-down list in order to ask for a users charisma modifier.

I am currently using the drop-list available using Java Swing.
The drop-down list I am using can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Todisplaysadialogwithalistofchoicesinadropdownlistbox.htm):

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Character_Charisma
{
    private static String input = "";

    public static int main() {
        int[] choices = {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int input = (int) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose now...",
            "What is your Charisma modifier?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
                                                                    // Use
                                                                    // default
                                                                    // icon
            choices, // Array of choices
            choices[0]); // Initial choice
            return input;
    }
}
```

I am struggling to return an integer with this code.

I am getting the error: "incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to java.lang.Object[]"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you read any tutorials on how to structure a Swing GUI program?  You're missing some basics, you cannot just instantiate a `JOptionPane` in a non-gui program, there's a certain amount of code required to get the GUI and event loop going that you have omitted.

Comment: I have gotten the Swing GUI working for a few other string inputs.
At the moment it is working well for what I needed.

I am using BlueJ to code my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Integer instead, as it inherits from the Object class.:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Character_Charisma
{
    private static String input = "";

    public static int main() {
        Integer[] choices = {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Integer input = (Integer) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose now...",
            "What is your Charisma modifier?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, 
                                                                    // Use
                                                                    // default
                                                                    // icon
            choices, // Array of choices
            choices[0]); // Initial choice
            return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it would be something simple.

Comment: I am not able to vote because I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: No you can up vote, may be because someone already down voted! I doubt his/her reason to down vote something which is correct.